# ¿Cómo puedo rescatar el texto de un input con VBA SELENIUM?

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy automatizando un proceso de altas, requiero saber el valor de una etiqueta input y meterla a una variable string.

He intentado esto, pero se queda vacío:

```
status = nav.FindElementById("a").text
```

Requiero conocer el valor de ese input y colocarlo en la variable.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Quizás `nav.FindElementById("a").Value`?

Comment: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Correcto, me ha funcionando con .VALUE Gracias!!

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Esto NO funciona como foro y usaste el campo Tu Respuesta pa decir Gracias ;) Estaría lindo si borras la no-respuesta, pones tu solución o le permites al otro usuario ponerla como respuesta :)

Comment: @Esei pon eso como respuesta, añadiendo un poco de detalle/código para completar la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Los controles de tipo input en HTML tienen una propiedad value para almacenar un valor.

> [HTML  value
> Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)

Con lo que el código debería funcionar con `nav.FindElementById("a").Value`